# Cloud highload web application based on Symfony and Angular

Tags: angular, symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Good day,
I develop a hightload application based on Symfony and Angular (v2).

There two different and absolutely independent apps :

1. api (server side) created on Symfony
2. user interface(client side) created on Angular (v2)

They communicate by Oauth v2.
So there two diffent and independent applications.

My goal is to deploy both on AWS.
For Symfony I use Elastic Beanstalk + RDS.
I use FREE User account for a moment.

My question : should I create another application on Elastic Beanstalk for Angular. That means I'll pay for another EC2.
Or could I install both Angular(clien) and Symfony(server) in the same Elastic Beanstalk application?

Please give me some advices to save money ant time.

Comment: I think that depend what is SPA to build? consider about speed, how many user will use, how fast you want to. If just simple SPA, just install both in same Elastic Beanstalk with server set port or sub domain or without it. Have you tried use Elastic Beanstalk? docker is good for one installation

Comment: @hendrathings for a moment it's a home project, so probably I'll use docker, this could be a good solution, and symfony application will use subdomain and Angular application will use normal domain naim.

Answer (score 0):

It will be cheaper and far more scalable for you to deploy your SPA ( Angular front end ) directly on CloudWatch while you keep your API on Elastic beanstalk.

EB is intended for handling your own servers but static content should be deployed on a proper Content Distribution Network (CDN). This way, as your user base grows, you won’t have to worry about managing ( and paying for ) more servers. The CDN will be able to handle your work load no matter how high it gets.

For the API, there is no way around having EC2 machines. Well, that’s not true either as you could move to AWS API Gateway + Lambda, but for your Synphony setup, you need Servers, and EB will help you grow as needed ( but you still want to avoid EC2 machines if you can have somebody else manage them for you ).

Comment: Thank you very much @dkarchmer, really good advices. I even did think about CloudWatch + EB. It should be really good solution for EB. And for symfony probably I'll try both. Anyway these experiments will give me aws skills.